# Unittesting a function containing an infinite loop

Tags: python, unit-testing

Given a function handling requests on a connection the body of the function is a infinite loop:

```
def handle_connection():
    # initialize stuff
    ...

    while True:
        # stuff to get the request
        ...

        # stuff to handle the request
        ...
```

How would I unittest this function?

Comment: Send it requests and look at the responses. Just like every other test.

Comment: You can run it in a separate thread, send it some predetermined inputs, and check the output by simulating the output interface it interacts with.

Comment: The simple answer: you don't run anything in a endless unbreakable loop. Make sure you have a way to exit from it. e.g. `while running:`.

Comment: You should refactor to have a functions `fetch_request()` (returns `request`), mock whatever source request comes from and check if it can successfully create `request` object (which is independent of whatever request source is). Next, you want to extract function  `handle_request(request)`, and test if `handle_request` works fine for given request description. Additional abstract layers and single purpose functions would help in testing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit it to run only once while testing, like:

```
a = 0
while True and not a:
    # do your stuff
    a = 1
```

that will not require you to change indentation,

or output specific content while running to make sure it gets the right values into the variables while running:

```
while True:
    # get request
    print(request)
    # interact with request
    print(data_achieved)
```

which will save you adding a variable.